# How to detect a workstation lock

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing an application and I'm trying to detect when the workstation gets locked, for example by the user pressing the Windows + L keys.

I know that the lock event has the value

```
  WTS_SESSION_LOCK 0x7
```

But i don't know how to use it. I've searched the web but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnallly managed to do it on VB :D

First you need to import the libs:

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

Then you add the handler:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    AddHandler SystemEvents.SessionSwitch, AddressOf SessionSwitch_Event

End Sub
```

Finnally you create the sub that captures it:

```
Private Sub SessionSwitch_Event(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SessionSwitchEventArgs)

    If e.Reason = SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock Then
        MsgBox("Locked")
    End If
    If e.Reason = SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock Then
        MsgBox("Unlocked")
    End If
End Sub
```

Last you remove the handler:

```
Private Sub closing_event(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    RemoveHandler SystemEvents.SessionSwitch, AddressOf SessionSwitch_Event
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [`SystemEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx) class in the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace, especially the [`SystemEvents.SessionSwitch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch.aspx) event.

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;  // Subscribe to the SessionSwitch event

static void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
        // Add your session lock "handling" code here
}
```

### Update

If you need to have this event activated from the program startup in a Winforms application:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;  // Subscribe to the SessionSwitch event

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    static void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
            // Add your session lock "handling" code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to be asking this but, with that code do i need the EventLog control?, And where do i place the code?

Comment: @Newbie With this, you don't need EventLog any more. And you subscribe the event when ever you need want. If you need it during all your program session, subcribe in the Program.Main() (I've edited my post to show you were to write the code in that case).

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry i forgot to mention but i'm using Visual Basic, i tried applying but it doesn't work :S