# .NET Key Down Event [Combination of Keys not working]

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, key, keydown

I'm a newbie in programming. Currently having issue with combination of key press.

**[LWin + L]**

```
Private Sub unit_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.L AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.LWin) Then
        MsgBox("Pressed!")
    End If
End Sub
```

The message box does not display. Tried KeyUp, PreviewKeyDown but no avail.

However, it works with other combination such as
**[Ctrl + L]**

```
If (e.KeyCode = Keys.L AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then
```

Stuck half day over here. Hope some pros can provide solution.

Thanks!

Comment: A keycode cannot both be L *and* Win+L.  You'll never get it, Win+L locks the workstation first.

Comment: @HansPassant Would like the application to perform the action while user lock the screen though. Is there any settings I can make on PC to make it work? (Like delay 1 second for lock screen?)

Thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant UPDATE: Found alternatives for LWin + L. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847744/how-to-detect-a-workstation-lock
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Keys.LWin` is technically not a modifier key you'll have to use a workaround to solve this.

Here's a rather simple one:

- Each time a key is pressed add it to a table.
- Check if the wanted key combination exists in our table, if it does then do whatever it is you want to do when it is pressed.
- When a key is released, remove it from the table.

Something like this should work:

```
'This is our table containing all currently pressed keys.
Private KeysPressed As New HashSet(Of Keys)

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    'Add the currently pressed key to the table.
    KeysPressed.Add(e.KeyCode)

    'Determine if the combination LWin + L exists in our table (thus, if it is currently pressed)
    If KeysPressed.Contains(Keys.LWin) AndAlso KeysPressed.Contains(Keys.L) Then
        'Clear all pressed keys to avoid possible issues.
        KeysPressed.Clear()

        'Do your stuff here...
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    'Remove the released key from the table.
    KeysPressed.Remove(e.KeyCode)
End Sub
```

You should probably use another key combination than <kbd>LWin</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, as it seems Windows doesn't send it to your application due to that it's also a shortcut for locking your computer.

Comment: Hi Vincent, thank you for your quick response.
I have tried your method, it jumps directly to lock screen.

However it works when with one key
If KeysPressed.Contains(Keys.LWin) Then
        'Do your stuff...
    End If

Comment: @Tim : Well, yes. One of Windows's built-in shortcut keys is `Win + L` which locks your computer. You cannot overcome that via code like this. If possible you should rather use another combination than `LWin + L`.

Comment: @Tim : I just updated my answer with a code fix. -- Any other combination than `LWin + L` appears to work (such as `LWin + K`), so it seems Windows is not sending the `LWin + L` combination to your application due to that it's a reserved shortcut. Otherwise it works for me!

Comment: @Vincent Thanks for the detailed explanation, I would like the application to perform the action while user lock the screen though. Is there any settings I can make on PC to make it work?

Comment: @Vincent UPDATE: Found alternatives for LWin + L. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847744/how-to-detect-a-workstation-lock
Thanks